# Read the consumer package.json from a package built using webpack in prepare script

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, package.json, consumer

I have a library that uses webpack to be bundled, I need to read the consumer package.json config passed to the library.
I tried:

```js
externals: [
    {
      'global-package': path.resolve(__dirname, '/../../../package.json')
    }
]
```

The library package.json scripts section is like this:

```js
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "webpack --mode=production"
   }
```

But when I try to install the package by installing the consumer app, It consider the external path in:

```sh
/home/user/.npm
```

Can you tell me how can I achieve that please?